# Rails Model-Association Form Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys, I'm having trouble understanding a Rails construct. I'm using Rails 3 but I doubt this is specific to this version.

I have a model, `Goal` that `has_many :commits` and naturally, a `Commit` model that `belongs_to :goal`. I created the proper migration so that `commits_table.references :goal`.

I am actually going through the [Rails Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide, except in that article they use a `Post` and `Comment` respectively.

Now that I've described the situation I can express my confusion. On the `Goal`'s **show** view, I have embedded a form to create a new Commit which is 'attached' to the currently viewed Goal. This works fine and all. However, I am having trouble understanding why we do this

```
<%= form_for([@goal, @goal.commits.build]) do |f| %>
```

Shouldn't it be `form_for(@commit)`? I understand why we want the `@goal`, to provide some context since the commit is a nested resource. However, in the actual generated source, the form is appropriately named as commit, that is, the fields are named `commit_blah`. How did Rails know this? I understand that there's this whole system of "trust and magic" and all, but I mean at least at the high level, what from this code hinted to Rails that I wanted a commit?

I looked at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) for form_for and it seems like one of the parameters could be the action to take for the form. I imagine that in this case, that's what the `@goal.commits.build` parameter is for? To designate the action to take? Is this how Rails deduces that I want a commit? Would this also explain why this form is handled by the `Commit` controller even though this code is in the Goal's view?

Also, why are these parameters passed as an array (`[]`)? In Ruby, will the method still just take it as two separate parameters, or is there a reason why this was passed this way?

Finally, `rails generate` automatically gave me some error showing code in my other `_form.html.erb` partials:

```
<% if @commit.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@commit.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this commit from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @commit.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I want to add this to this embedded form, how would I do so? I guess my question is, what would I use in place of `@commit`?

Thanks. I'm just trying to get my head around these new concepts.

Comment: Regarding your question about the purpose of @goal in 'form_for([@goal, @goal.commits.build])'. It's kind of hard to see in the Rails code, but that array gets passed on to various other Rails methods. Ultimately, Rails will build a nested route ('/goals/1/commits/new') for you with information from that array. From the 'form_for' code, you have to go look at the code for #apply_form_for_options!(record_or_name_or_array, options) -> #polymorphic_path() -> #polymorphic_url -> #build_named_route_call.

Comment: So I guess the 'convention' is to pass the 'context', so to speak, so that it can build the nested resource. The 'convention' is also to make the last element of the array be what we actually want to build. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go back to the documentation and click 'show source', you'll see

```
def form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
  ...
  case record_or_name_or_array
  when String, Symbol
    ...
  when Array
    object = record_or_name_or_array.last
    object_name = options[:as] || ActiveModel::Naming.singular(object)
    apply_form_for_options!(record_or_name_or_array, options)
    args.unshift object
  else
    ...
  end
  ...
  output << fields_for(object_name, *(args << options), &proc)
  ...
```

For form_for, the first parameter can be a record, name or an array.  In your case, you pass it an array.  The code then determines the 'object' as the last member of that array, which is your @goal.commits.build object. The object name is determined from the [ActiveModel::Naming.singular](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-c-singular) method.

```
console > ActiveModel::Naming.singular(@goal.commits.build)
=> "commit"
```

Then it generated the appropriate form fields using fields_for and 'commit'.

Comment: Thanks monocle. Just one more question, what's the point of passing the @goal in the array if what form_for goes off of is @goal.commits.build? I checked the source but didn't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using nested resources.  Check your routes.rb file to see if you have something like:

map.resources :commits, :has_many => :goals

or perhaps:

map.resources :commits do |commit|
  commit.resources :goals
end

If that is the case, then you will need to supply both the commit and goal objects to the form_for method.

Comment: Thanks. If you read my question, I did state that I was using nested resources. In fact, I don't know if you know what I'm even asking. Everything is working perfectly fine, it's just that I don't understand why it's necessary to do it this way.

Comment: I read your email, but I guess I mis-understood what you were asking.  However, as I mentioned, you have to supply both because it is a nested resource, it can't create a valid URL without knowing which commit owns the goal.  E.g. the path should be something like /commit/:id/goals/:id, it can't create that without knowing about both the commit and goal.